# About "Easy does it"

Tags: expressions

Why is "does" used as in this expression "easy does it", can it be "do" because an implied subject should be "you"? and can you introduce similar expressions that have such a construction?

I'm supposing that "does" might have been fixed for keeping the grammatical rule, as "easy" is pretending to be functioning as a singular subject because of its position although it works as an adverb modifying "does" in fact.

Comment: All I can say is that **easy does it** is a fixed expression. An expression with a similar structure, I think, would be **that does it**: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/that-does-it

Comment: In my opinion the word "easy" is standing for some noun phrase left implied. If someone is advising you to move slowly and gently to avoid breaking something or knocking something over, he says "Easy does it," meaning that "easy" (that is, slow gentle action) does the trick, or does the job.

Comment: My analysis suggests an analogy to the saying "Slow and steady wins the race," where "slow" and "steady," although they are adjectives, are being used to suggest some noun, like "slow and steady progress."

Comment: As suggested by some other comments, perhaps it started off as something like *Doing it easily will get it done,* and the implied subject has remained *it*. Like the null subject (*it's raining*).